# Renaming a default taxonomy field ('description') in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to either utilize the `description` field in a custom taxonomy I'm building but rename it to `bio`, or remove `description` altogether and create the new field on my own.

Any idea what I need to do either of these?

Comment: There is no `description` field within a custom taxonomy.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Isn't there? I always have Name, Slug, and Description in custom non-hierarchical taxonomies withut specifying them in register_taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

What about this jQuery hack? Place it in *functions.php* of your theme or create a simple plugin:

```
function rename_category_description() { 
    global $current_screen;
    if ( $current_screen->id == 'edit-category' ) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('document').ready(function() {
            jQuery("label[for='tag-description']").text("Bio");
        });
        </script>
<?php }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'rename_category_description');
```